# List of versions of WriteLine missing from parenthese in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to follow a tutorial in Visual Studio and I notice in the lesson that the teacher is able to scroll through all the 19 different versions of WriteLine if he clicks in the parenthesis and when I try to follow, clicking the down arrow, my cursor just travels down the Visual Studio page and I am unable the scroll though different versions of WriteLine. I've attached two screenshots to clarify what I mean. Any feedback would be great.

[image: enter image description]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quiet simple, while your typing cursor is between the two brackets,

press Ctrl + Shift + Space

Then the scrollable window will open, and you will be free to scrool through the overloads with the down/up arrow keys.